React render iframe in the same state elsewhere in app
I have a scenario in react where we render a BI dashboard via an iframe on the page, the user can interact with the frame, perhaps filtering the BI data etc.
I have build functionality to enable this iframe to be expanded into a full screen dialog for better user experience. However I want to be able to render the exact same frame so any filters would still be applied and the BI dashboard to not need to load from scratch (it takes some time).
Is this possible in React?
Tried to conditionally wrap the component in the dialog.

You can use a react state to control whether to show the dialog.
If state is true, set display attribute of Dialog to block,otherwise to none.So that the iframe inside the dialog will not reload again.


import {useState} from 'react';

export default function DashBoard(){
  const [show,setShow]=useState(false);
  return <Dialog style={{display: show ? 'block' : 'none'}}>
    <iframe src = 'xxx'></iframe>
  </Dialog>;
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>



